# Unable to Import Google Protobuf Python Module

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, protocol-buffers

I am working with an Ubuntu 14.04 machine, trying to import the google.protobuf module into python 2.7.

I have tried

```
apt-get python-protobuf
```

and

```
pip install protobuf
```

without success.

Inside python, I get an error saying:

> "ImportError: No module named google.protobuf"

**Edit 1:**

Sorry and thank you to everyone who commented. I'm still new to Ubuntu and StackOverflow.

Specifically, I type in to command line

```
python
import google.protobuf
```

and get the feedback

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>
> ImportError: No module named google.protobuf

I then type

```
exit()
```

I tried inputting

```
sudo apt-get install python-protobuf
```

which responds with

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   python-protobuf is already the newest version.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 283 not upgraded.

Then I go back into python and try

```
import google.protobuf
```

again, but I get exactly the same error as before.

Finally, I tried

```
pip install protobuf
```

which responded with

> Requirement already satisfied: protobuf in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>
> Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from protobuf)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from protobuf)

I tried

```
python
import google.protobuf
```

and got exactly the same error. Putting

```
import protobuf
```

into python also gets the same error.

Some related information: I have tried doing multiple uninstalls/reinstalls with both apt-get and pip to fix th error, with no change. Also, one of the first things I did after getting Ubuntu was to download python 2.7 from the website and install it, not realizing python came with Ubuntu.

Thanks again.

Comment: i'm may not be correct, but try just `import protobuf` with the `google.` part.
If that doesn't work, likely something is wrong with your pip.

Comment: you need to added details of your trouble, what do you mean `without success.`

Comment: Please show your code or the trace in the terminal with the error. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: very late to the party, but try `$ python -m pip install protobuf`. To me this smells like classic using-pip-for-different-python-version/instalation problem. To find out which python version does the `pip` command correspond try `$ which pip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install --ignore-installed six

sudo pip install protobuf
```